# python filter throwing up strange errors

Tags: python, filter

I have a list and a filter like so:

```
matrix = [['X', 'X', 'X'], ['X', 'X', 'X'], ['X', 'X', 'X'], ['O', 'X', 'X'], ['O', 'X', 'X']] 
s = list(zip(*matrix)[0])

print s[s != 'X']
```

When I run this it returns `'X'`

If it is modified to:

```
matrix = [['X', 'X', 'X'], ['O', 'X', 'X'], ['X', 'X', 'X'], ['O', 'X', 'X'], ['O', 'X', 'X']] 
s = list(zip(*matrix)[0])

print s[s != 'X']
```

It then returns `'O'`.

I've googled/stack searched it to death but can't seem to find what is going on with this. What am I missing here that makes it not exclude all 'X' values?

Comment: What are you expecting?

Comment: In both cases was expecting it to filter out values of 'X'...

Comment: So you want to keep the same list format from before?  `s = list(zip(*matrix)[0])` just builds a list with the 0th element from each nested list, then `print s[s != 'X']` prints the element preceding the first 'X' in your list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code, it is giving the correct values only.

When you run the first code,

```
>>> matrix = [['X', 'X', 'X'], ['X', 'X', 'X'], ['X', 'X', 'X'], ['O', 'X', 'X'], ['O', 'X', 'X']] 
>>> s = list(zip(*matrix)[0])
```

The value of `s` is a list,

```
>>> print s
['X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O']
```

Now when you compare `s` with a literal for inequality, it obviously gives you True

```
>>> s!= "X"
True
```

This True is internally treated as an index to s, and gets converted to 1:

```
>>> True == 1
True
>>> s[s!="X"]
'X'
>>> s[1]
'X'
```

In the second case, the value of `s` is different:

```
>>> matrix = [['X', 'X', 'X'], ['O', 'X', 'X'], ['X', 'X', 'X'], ['O', 'X', 'X'], ['O', 'X', 'X']] 
>>> s = list(zip(*matrix)[0])
>>> print s
['X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'O']
>>> s[1]
'O'
```

And hence `"O"` is printed.

Comment: Right, makes perfect sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To correctly filter out `'X'`, use the actual [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) function.

```
>>>[filter(lambda x : x != 'X', sublist) for sublist in matrix]
[[], [], [], ['O'], ['O']]
>>>
```

Comment: Or equally `[[s for s in d if s != 'X'] for d in matrix]`

Comment: Yep this is perfect. Thanks again for the answers :)